# Use Buttons created with JavaScript to call functions

Tags: javascript

I retrieving an list of events from an online service, to display the result I dynamically create HTML div which include the information and button.

```
for(var i = 0; i < EventsArray.length; i++)
    {
        console.log(EventsArray[i]);

        var EventLine = document.createElement("div");
        EventLine.style.display="inline";

        var element = document.createElement("p");

        var Event = document.createTextNode(EventsArray[i][0]+' '+EventsArray[i][2]);
        element.appendChild(Event);

        var button = document.createElement("input");
        //Assign different attributes to the element. 
        button.type = "button";
        button.value = "Re-Invite Users"; 
        button.name = "Re-Invite";              

        button.onclick = 
        function(EventsArray) {
            var nonReplying = new Array(getNoreply(EventsArray[i][1])); 
            //unInviteUsers(EventsArray[i][1], nonReplying);
        };          

        EventLine.appendChild(element);
        EventLine.appendChild(button);
        eventsList = document.getElementById("Events");
        eventsList.appendChild(EventLine);

    }
```

Everything works well except the button:

```
button.onclick = 
        function(EventsArray) {
            var nonReplying = new Array(getNoreply(EventsArray[i][1])); 
            //unInviteUsers(EventsArray[i][1], nonReplying);
        };
```

When running it an error occurs:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'EventsArray[i][1]')

Since EventsArray does not exists when the webpage loads I'm not able set button.onlick up...

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your function inside a closure to get the value of an item inside a loop or using bind to create a new function with a default argument.

Test on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BwVNC/

```
function getNoreply(item) {
    return "noreply" + item;
}

var EventsArray = [
    ['first0', 0, 'third0'],
    ['first1', 1, 'third1'],
    ['first2', 2, 'third2'],
    ['first3', 3, 'third3'],
]

for(var i = 0; i < EventsArray.length; i++)
    {
        console.log(EventsArray[i]);

        var EventLine = document.createElement("div");
        EventLine.style.display="inline";

        var element = document.createElement("p");

        var Event = document.createTextNode(EventsArray[i][0]+' '+EventsArray[i][2]);
        element.appendChild(Event);

        var button = document.createElement("input");
        //Assign different attributes to the element. 
        button.type = "button";
        button.value = "Re-Invite Users"; 
        button.name = "Re-Invite";              

        button.onclick = function(item) {
            var nonReplying = new Array(getNoreply(item)); 
            console.log(nonReplying);
        }.bind(button, EventsArray[i][1]);

        EventLine.appendChild(element);
        EventLine.appendChild(button);
        eventsList = document.getElementById("Events");
        eventsList.appendChild(EventLine);

    }
```

Comment: you could also bind or wrap i inside the closure and use EventsArray[theBindedI][1]

Comment: that's nice but what does .bind exactly do?

Comment: Best explanation there: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just remove the parameter?

```
button.onclick = 
    function() {
        var nonReplying = new Array(getNoreply(EventsArray[i][1])); 
        //unInviteUsers(EventsArray[i][1], nonReplying);
    };
```

Comment: getNoreply() and unInviteUsers() also get called with the undefined objet

Comment: If you remove EventsArray as a parameter then you get EventsArray from the code above (closure). But you added a new parameter that will make EventsArray undefined since the onClick event doesn't send EventsArray as argument.

Comment: I think I found the error, if the user clicks on the actual HTML button, the function can not get EventsArray[i][1]s content.